Clarification of converting Implicit outer joins to ANSI joins
As part of the modernization effort (move from Sybase ASE to SQL Server), we are removing old implicit join operators and rewriting SQL using ANSI join style.
When running both queries, I saw that my new query was wrong (returned fewer rows) and figured out how to fix it...
Implicit join SQL:
SELECT c.code_id ,  
    c.code_type_id ,  
    c.code_desc,  
    'N' AS orig_status,  
    'N' AS current_status,  
    sr.staff_role_id AS staff_role_id 
FROM code c, staff_role sr 
WHERE c.code_id *= sr.staff_role_cd 
    AND c.code_type_id = :app_cd  -- strings beginning with : are parameters to be swapped out, like @app_cd.
    AND code_active = 'Y'  
    AND sr.staff_id = :staff_id 

Fixed ANSI join style SQL
SELECT c.code_id ,  
    c.code_type_id,  
    c.code_desc,  
    'N' AS orig_status,  
    'N' AS current_status,  
    sr.staff_role_id AS staff_role_id 
FROM code c  
LEFT OUTER JOIN  staff_role AS sr ON (c.code_id = sr.staff_role_cd)  
    AND sr.staff_id = :staff_id  " <---- WHY did this need to move here?
WHERE 
    c.code_type_id = :app_cd 
    AND code_active = 'Y'  
    //<- sr.staff_id check used to be here...

I get that the table uses staff_id in it's join, but I don't understand why it had to be moved from the where clause and into the on clause.
staff_role_code is a table that lets us connect a
staff(staff table, PK staff_id),
to the code (Code table, PK code_id, contains the code for all the roles, (and a bunch of other stuff))
That's used for a role.
So I don't understand why we needed to move the staff_id check, but not the code check.
What exactly is changed with and in the join clause instead of the where, and what does it do?
How do I identify when this change is needed in the future? All I have now is running both SQL in the ASE database and seeing if the results match.
Note on possible duplicate
Please notice that the table that was added was not the right or left-hand table in the outer join, so the linked questions don't seem to address this particular case, where the added "join" is on a Foreign Key shared by the two tables, not a primary key of either of the tables.

Note that both implicit and explicit joins are ANSI/ISO SQL.

I was wondering why AND sr.staff_id = :staff_id didn't need AND sr.staff_id *= :staff_id to work but apparently sql server rewrites the implicit join as something like: select * from (select * from table1 where <all stuff that selects from it>) x cross (or inner or left/right join) join (select * from table2 where <all stuff that selects from it>) y <ON joined conditions if any> One learns something every day

@jarlh - the use of *= for outer join (as in this question) is not ANSI/ISO

@MartinSmith, correct. I did just read the title.

this answer does a pretty good job describing the on clause vs where clause question with a working set of data; make note of the first 2 lines of the answer ... for inner joins they effectively behave the same ... it's outer joins where the issue arises and can lead to different results (as in your case)

The old joins have been obsolete for 30 years now,  so about time they made this move. But to address the question: if that conditional expression is part of the WHERE clause, instead of an ON predicate, it has the effect of making the OUTER JOIN give the same results as an INNER JOIN, because NULL rows would be excluded.

Or, put another way, you could modify the where clause to correctly handle rows that aren't matched, e.g. a left outer join would need ... and ( sr.staff_id = :staff_id or sr.staff_id is NULL ) because staff_role (alias sr) is on the right side of the join and may not produce a matching row.
